# Devolver los datos ordenados en un dataset y mostrarlos en un formulario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, reportviewer

Tengo un dataset que devuelve estos datos ordenados por la columna uds en forma descendente tal como muestra el ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tengo cuando rellendo el dataset para pasarselo al reportviewer lo hago de esta forma , los datos no me salen ordenados de forma descendente por el campo uds

```
      private void frmVentasTop10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ventasLiniasTableAdapter.obtenerLiniasOrdenadasPorUnidades(this.dSVentasLinias.VentasLinias, pFechaInicio, pFechaFin);
        try
        {
            ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("proveedor", pProveedor.ToString());
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p1);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

Esto me devuelve el informe con los datos pero no me ordena por la columna "uds" de forma descendente , el resultado por pantalla es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las propiedades de la tabla "**tablix**" tengo que ordene por el campo **uds** pero no lo hace.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Con lo poco que se puede observar supongo que te lo está ordenando por `Código de Artículo`, y que lo está considerando como string, por eso el 10 al inicio de la lista. Lo que yo hago (no se qué tan recomendable sea) es ordenar los datos desde la consulta, así en la vista ya no hay qué ordenar nada.